# Ansible tasks for adding the Google Cloud SDK apt repository signing key

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ansible, apt

I'm trying to download and install the Google Cloud SDK apt repository's signing key as a set of Ansible tasks. (i.e., Converting the manual process outlined [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install) into Ansible).

This is what I've come up with:

```yaml
- name: Install the Google Cloud SDK package repository signing key
  ansible.builtin.apt_key:
    url: https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg
    keyring: /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg

- name: Add Google Cloud SDK package repository source
  ansible.builtin.apt_repository:
    filename: google-cloud-sdk.list
    repo: "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main"
    update_cache: yes
```

However, my first task fails, with a big GnuPG error. Here's the Ansible failure JSON:

```json
{
  "changed": false,
  "msg": "Unable to extract key from '-'",
  "stderr": "gpg: WARNING: no command supplied.  Trying to guess what you mean ...\ngpg: [don't know]: invalid packet (ctb=0a)\n",
  "stderr_lines": [
    "gpg: WARNING: no command supplied.  Trying to guess what you mean ...",
    "gpg: [don't know]: invalid packet (ctb=0a)"
  ],
  "stdout": "pub:-:2048:1:FEEA9169307EA071:1614614617:1677728521::-:\nuid:::::::::Rapture Automatic Signing Key (cloud-rapture-signing-key-2021-03-01-08_01_09.pub):\nsub:-:2048:1:AA42F36EE8BEEE0E:1614614617::::\npub:-:2048:1:8B57C5C2836F4BEB:1607040606:1670154510::-:\nuid:::::::::gLinux Rapture Automatic Signing Key (//depot/google3/production/borg/cloud-rapture/keys/cloud-rapture-pubkeys/cloud-rapture-signing-key-2020-12-03-16_08_05.pub) <glinux-team@google.com>:\nsub:-:2048:1:48419E688DD52AC0:1607040606::::\n",
  "stdout_lines": [
    "pub:-:2048:1:FEEA9169307EA071:1614614617:1677728521::-:",
    "uid:::::::::Rapture Automatic Signing Key (cloud-rapture-signing-key-2021-03-01-08_01_09.pub):",
    "sub:-:2048:1:AA42F36EE8BEEE0E:1614614617::::",
    "pub:-:2048:1:8B57C5C2836F4BEB:1607040606:1670154510::-:",
    "uid:::::::::gLinux Rapture Automatic Signing Key (//depot/google3/production/borg/cloud-rapture/keys/cloud-rapture-pubkeys/cloud-rapture-signing-key-2020-12-03-16_08_05.pub) <glinux-team@google.com>:",
    "sub:-:2048:1:48419E688DD52AC0:1607040606::::"
  ]
}
```

If I download the file from Google (with `get_url`) and add the key that way -- which doesn't seem necessary, from my understanding of the documentation -- it progresses, but then the second task fails (because the key's not found).

I assume I'm using `apt_key` and `apt_repository` incorrectly, but I don't know how. Can it be done this way, or would it be easier to just shell out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently `apt-key` is deprecated. I got it to work with:

```yaml
- name: Download the Google Cloud SDK package repository signing key
  ansible.builtin.get_url:
    url: https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg
    dest: /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/gcloud.gpg

- name: Add Google Cloud SDK package repository source
  ansible.builtin.apt_repository:
    filename: google-cloud-sdk.list
    repo: "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/gcloud.gpg] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main"
    update_cache: yes
```

Comment: For me, `[signed-by=…` wasn’t necessary. Maybe it picks up the key automatically when it’s in `trusted.gpg.d`?

Comment: You just saved me a lot of time. Thanks.

Comment: @aaronk6 yes, this is why; and [this is why it is not a good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71384057) to store third party signing key in `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/` directory. Use `/usr/share/keyrings/` instead, and [always use](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/UseThirdParty#OpenPGP_Key_distribution) `signed-by` in your `.list` file! @Xophmeister

Comment: Add the keys to `/etc/apt/keyrings/` which is where file managed by the sysadmin go. `/usr/share/keyrings/` is for files owned and managed by packages. Please read `man 5 sources.list`.

Answer (score 6):

TL;DR (tested on debian 11) - addendum to Xophmeister's solution:

- use /usr/share/keyrings for 3rd party gpg keys (/etc/apt/keyrings for debian 12+, also below for consistency)
- put signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/key.(gpg|asc) in repo definition
- prefer binary signatures (.gpg files), but ascii armored keys seems to work (as long as the extension is .asc)
- no need to install gnupg (as long as you don't use apt-key commands)

Although Xophmeister answer seems to be ok, it misses the whole point for the apt-key deprecation, which is to not add anymore 3rd party keys to the global signing key list.
So, the idea is to create a new directory (/usr/share/keyrings, /usr/local/share/keyrings etc) and put there all 3rd party signing keys, and leave trusted.gpg.d only for official debian repositories.

LE: /usr/share/keyrings is present in debian since debian 9 (at least), and this is the default location where you should put the keys; probably in the future /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ will be deprecated (even for debian keys, now only for third party keys)

since debian 12 the right directory should be /etc/apt/keyrings
debian 11 and below don't come with that directory, so to be consistent you must create that directory as root/root/0775
(thanks @starfish for the info!)

use .gpg for binary keys (preferred), and .asc for ascii armored; although ascii armored keys are not recommended, because we talk about ansible playbooks it is hard (for now) to write good code (idempotent way) that will get the ascii key and transform it to binary; of course, I guess we can use apt_key module as before and set the destination in the /usr/share/keyrings directory; but as long as it probably uses the apt-key script in the background, this probably is not the best option

so, using get_url and apt_repository I was able to add an ascii armored key and the repository with signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/key.asc; no need to install gnupg; apt update and apt install worked; binary key is recommended, but seems to work also with ascii armored key

Comment: Thanks for this additional information. When I was doing this, I could find very little about the correct procedure.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30026150)

Comment: I agree, that should be a comment. But it seems what my reputation is not enough to comment, so as long as my "comment" adds some value to the solution the "mistake" can be overlooked :-P

Comment: Add the keys to `/etc/apt/keyrings/` which is where file managed by the sysadmin go. `/usr/share/keyrings/` is for files owned and managed by packages. Please read `man 5 sources.list`.

Comment: @Starfish: well, you seems to be right, as stated on https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/UseThirdParty, /etc/apt/keyrings is the right directory since debian 12; but that directory does not exists on deb 11 and below (quote: "In releases older than Debian 12 and Ubuntu 22.04, /etc/apt/keyrings does not exist by default. It SHOULD be created with permissions 0755 if it is needed and does not already exist.")
thanks for the tip, if you have some info (i.e. some docs or mail thread) about this "change of heart", that will be appreciated