# What is this error when trying to update Ubuntu?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I am need of updating my Ubuntu(using 18.04.4 LTS) machine so I can update NodeJS to the latest version.

Whenever I run 'sudo apt update' I get this error:

```
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY {A KEY IS HERE}
```

I get it for two keys.

When I use the command below it works for one key but I still get the same errors when running the update command again.

```
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys {KEY}
```

Comment: See https://chrisjean.com/fix-apt-get-update-the-following-signatures-couldnt-be-verified-because-the-public-key-is-not-available/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70789307/how-to-fix-the-following-signatures-couldnt-be-verified-because-the-public-key