# The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available while updating sudo apt update

Tags: linux, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to install some application on Ubuntu 20.04, for that I am trying to run command on terminal

```
$ sudo apt update
```

and I have got following error

```
Err:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 78BD65473CB3BD13
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am got the same issue while running the below command

```
$ sudo apt update
```

In your case, you can follow below option to resolved these issue.

1. `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 78BD65473CB3BD13`

   Or
2. `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 78BD65473CB3BD13`

In first option, we don't have to decide which port should be or you can go with second option. Either way, both will work.

Comment: Tip: this is not limited to ubuntu packages (myself had problems updating influxdb and grafana)

Answer (score 2):

Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).

To avoid the warning, add the package specific file with the key to the `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/` directory. The keys can be in several file formats like .asc, .gpg etc.
To add new PUBKEY:

```
    wget -qO- URL/PUBKEY.asc | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/APPNAME.asc
```

If the key is in the binary ('armored') format, dearmor it first:

```
    curl -s URL/PUBKEY.gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor | sudo tee  /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/APPNAME.gpg --import
```

Reference: [apt-key deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68992799/warning-apt-key-is-deprecated-manage-keyring-files-in-trusted-gpg-d-instead)

Comment: This should have been a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Note that placing keys in /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ isn't any better than using apt-key (security wise), see the accepted answer to the referenced question.